# Maximum distance traversed in an ideal projectile motion

Tags: classical-mechanics, projectile

In a projectile motion, consider the projectile to be launched from $(0,0)$ as traced to be on cartesian axes. Then the trajectory is given by
$$y=x \tan \theta \big(1-x/R)$$
where $\theta$ is measured from $x$ axis , and gravity acts along $y$ axis, $R$ stands for the maximum range which may vary with the initial velocity which has a magnitude of $v$.

Using arc length formula of a general curve,
$$dl=\int\sqrt{1+(\frac{dy}{dx})^2}\ dx$$
we get the distance traversed as an integral of form D=$\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}$

An interactive model can be found [here.](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/jdxofl4vti)

---

**My Question:** How do I find at what angle $\theta$ the distance travelled by the projectile will be maximized, given a fixed $v$.

---

I tried doing
$$\frac{d}{d \theta}D=0$$ but it gave me an unknown $\frac{dx}{d \theta}$, I am unable to approach further, so I created a [graph here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/m2qmi14fzs) and found that the it is near to $56.4^\circ$ but I am not sure if it is fixed.

Comment: So what is your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method is not too bad at the start, except that you seem to have ignored (or at least not stated clearly) that $R$ depends on $\theta$ as well, which is what makes this problem quite hard to solve. If I've understood you correctly, you would like to find the value of $\theta$ (for a fixed speed $u$) that maximises the total length of the projectile in the air. In this case, taking derivatives like $\frac{\text{d}x}{\text{d}\theta}$ is not sensible. The variables that you want to maximise with respect to are $a,b,$ and $c$, since you will be integrating over $x$!

Despite how convinced I initially was that this problem should have a simple analytical result, it seems to not be the case! As far as I can see, to truly solve it, you need to use numerical methods. If anyone knows of a better way, I'd be *very* interested. Let me explain what I did.

I decided to make the following assumptions:

1. The total velocity (a constant) is 1. This is not a problem, I've just chosen units in which $u=1$, which is perfectly acceptable.
2. I will only be varying $u_y$, given the above constraint. The value of $u_x$ will be fixed by $\sqrt{1 - u_y^2}$.

As you've pointed out (but formulated slightly differently) the total length covered by the projectile is:

$$L = \int_{0}^{2u_y/g}\sqrt{\left(\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}t}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\text{d}x}{\text{d}t}\right)^2} \text{d}t$$

(In this case, I have chosen to parameterise the curve by the time $t$, which I integrate from $t=0$ to $t=2 u_y/g$, which can be easily shown to be the total time of flight. You could do it your way too.)

Using the fact that

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
y &= u_y t - \frac{1}{2}g t^2,\\
x &= u_x t,
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

it's easy to show that

$$L = \int_{0}^{2u_y/g}\sqrt{(u_y-gt)^2 + u_x^2} \,\,\text{d}t = \int_{0}^{2u_y/g}\sqrt{u^2 - 2u_y g t + g^2 t^2} \,\,\text{d}t.$$

At times like this, it's useful to "adimensionalise" the equation, so that the limits don't depend on $u_y$. We can define a "dimensionless" time $$\tau = \frac{g}{2u_y}t,$$ so that the integral becomes:

$$L = \frac{2}{g} \int_{0}^{1}u_y\sqrt{u^2 - 4 u_y^2 \tau + 4 u_y^2 \tau^2} \,\,\text{d}\tau,$$

which is quite a nasty integral to solve by hand. Perhaps the people over at [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com) would be able to do it justice? [I decided to use *Mathematica* to solve it](https://www.smbc-comics.com/comic/2013-01-20).

I first integrated the function numerically and plotted the integral for different values of $u_y$ as shown below, and was surprised to find that $L$ did have a maximum value (my initial thought was perhaps that it didn't) for  $u_y$ somewhere between 0.82 and 0.84. [image]

Given this, I got *Mathematica* to integrate the function and found that

$$L =  \frac{1}{2g}\left( 2 u u_y + (u_y^2 - u^2) \ln\left({\frac{u - u_y}{u+u_y}}\right)\right).$$

There is nothing stopping us from using units where $u=1$ and therefore $u_y \in (0,1)$, and in these units

$$L= \frac{1}{2g}\left( 2 u_y + (u_y^2 - 1) \ln\left({\frac{1 - u_y}{1+u_y}}\right)\right).$$

Next, I attempted to maximise this as a function of $u_y$ by taking the derivative and equating it to zero, which leads to:

$$2 + u_y \ln\left({\frac{1 - u_y}{1 + u_y}}\right) = 0.$$

This is a transcendental equation and as such not easily solvable. But it's not too hard to solve it numerically to find that $L$ is maximised when $$u_y = 0.833557,$$

which lies in the range we expected. This corresponds to an angle of $$\theta = \arctan{\frac{u_y}{\sqrt{1 - u_y^2}}} = 0.985516 \text{ rad} \approx 56.466^\circ.$$

Comment: Nicely presented. I didnt think not mentioning well about the range would have implications, I am sorry if it could have been faster. Also, the function L, which is equivalent to the form of D is integrable using standard properties....trying those gave even harder to solve angles. Also, thanks for putting in the efforts, cheers

Comment: I ran this problem as a numeric simulation on a spreadsheet and got a result that agrees well with this one.

Comment: @R.W.Bird Yay! It's a cute question, and I think it could make a nice undergraduate "take-home" problem: not obvious, and requiring some numerical methods to solve.

Comment: How can your final form for $L$ not depend on $u$ since $u$ appears explicitly inside the integral? or is your $u_y$ really $u_y/u$?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero You're completely right that it should appear, of course. As I mentioned above, I am using units in which $u=1$ in my calculations, and I skipped a step. I'll fix it right now. What I find *more* disturbing is that $g$ doesn't play a more prominent part. I mean, if $g\to 0$ then $L_\text{max}\to\infty$ of course, but for all non-zero $g$, $L_\text{max}$ is the same. Isn't that strange?

Comment: Please ignore my earlier comment on the absence of $g$, that was a solving error, fixed by the OP in an edit.